# dispatch and _synchronized_subscribe RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am trying to understand core logic of RxSwift and I have simple button which will trigger and prints console when onNext(5) trigger.

I am following the Thread from left side of Xcode as below.

-RxSwift Library

```
// Step 1
  public func onNext(_ element: E) {
        self.on(.next(element))
    }
// Step 2
    public func on(_ event: Event<Element>) {
        #if DEBUG
            self._synchronizationTracker.register(synchronizationErrorMessage: .default)
            defer { self._synchronizationTracker.unregister() }
        #endif
        dispatch(self._synchronized_on(event), event)
    }
//Step 3
@inline(__always)
func dispatch<E>(_ bag: Bag<(Event<E>) -> Void>, _ event: Event<E>) {
    bag._value0?(event) 
/// after dispatch calling, it is creating BagKey as below
    func synchronized_subscribe<O: ObserverType>(_ observer: O) -> Disposable where O.E == E {
        if let stoppedEvent = self._stoppedEvent {
            observer.on(stoppedEvent)
            return Disposables.create()
        }
        
        if self._isDisposed {
            observer.on(.error(RxError.disposed(object: self)))
            return Disposables.create()
        }
        
        let key = self._observers.insert(observer.on) // directly flow comes here and my question is related with this step
        return SubscriptionDisposable(owner: self, key: key)
    }
// Step 4
        MapSink.on(_:)
// Step 5 FilterSink - PublishSubject... and flow goes on prints
```

---

- My Code

  ```
  import UIKit
  import RxSwift

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        let publisher = PublishSubject<Int>()
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        publisher
                .map { $0 * 2}
                .filter { $0 > 4 }
                .subscribe(onNext: { n in
                    print("We've got number \(n)!")
                })
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    @IBAction func trigger(_ sender: Any) {
        print("button triggered")
        publisher.onNext(5)
    }
   }
  ```

My question is what is going on at Step 3 , Can you explain please? Also I checked out the `synchronized_subscribe<O: ObserverType>` function calling place but could not find it; thread directly create a key and comes to inside of this function. How come RxSwift jumps to there even tough it is not called, What is the magic ?

Comment: What version of RxSwift are you using? This isn't the latest...

Comment: updated latest version but code is almost same. updated question as well.

Comment: Having asked a question so broad that it is almost meaningless ("what is going on"), this is then followed by yet another question. "Needs focus" is a stock reason for closure. To ward it off, it helps to be quite specific: one question about one clear thing.

Comment: Hint: do you see that `func synchronized_subscribe...` is _inside_ another `func`?

Comment: All of the functions are called, so I'm not sure what you mean by "How come RxSwift jumps to there even tough it is not called".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is really being asked here... The logic is that when `onNext(5)` is called, it will send a `Event.next(5)` to each of its subscribers (of which there is only one.)

As for what functions are called, the chain is like this:

```
ObserverType.onNext(_ element: Element)
    PublishSubject<Element>.on(_ event: Event<Element>)
        PublishSubject<Element>.synchronized_on(_ event: Event<Element>) // gets Bag of observers
        dispatch<Element>(_ bag: Bag<(Event<Element>) -> Void>, _ event: Event<Element>) // dispatches event to each observer in the bag.
            MapSink<SourceType, Observer: ObserverType>.on(_ event: Event<Self.Element>) // this is one of the observers.
```

You seem to be confused by the `dispatch(_:_:)` function. This function takes a Bag of observers (strictly speaking, a container of closures that accept `Event`s) and sends the event to the one Observer contained in the Bag.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I am not sure how should I ask to understand about this flow but I will try to be more focus.